# How to stop in strut2 <sx:submit onClick="return myfunction(a, b)" /> from submitting form when function returns false

Tags: ajax, struts2, dojo

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>


 <html>
 <head>
  <sx:head cache="true" />
<script>
   myfunction(a, b)
  {
      if ( a> b) 
      return true;
      else
      return false;   


  }
 </script>

</head>
```

....

```
 <s:form  action="saveXXXX"  >

  .... fields....                    

  <s:submit onclick="return myfunction(a, b);" />  //THIS ONE WORKS - NON AJAX
  <sx:submit onclick="return myfunction(a, b);" /> //Using sx ajax tag 
<sj:submit onclick="return myfunction(a, b);" id="formSubmit1" targets="formResult"  value="AJAX Submit" button="true" />  //if using Jquery Plugin ajax tag

 //how to stop form submittal if function returns false.    

  </s:form>
```

The form works using     s:submit .. but now that I'm trying to ajaxfy it with     sx:submit ... or jquery's sj:submit ...

I want to submit the form CONDITIONALLY using AJAX based on what the function returns.

How can it be done?

Comment: are you working on some old struts2 version/application ? Dojo tags are deprecated and no longer supported.

Comment: Even if switch it to JQuery Plugin. so .. now 
<sj:submit onclick="return myfunction(a, b);" id="formSubmit1" targets="formResult" value="AJAX Submit" button="true" />
I want to submit the FORM CONDITIONALLY based on return value from function

Comment: Upgrade - it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using submit button use a simple button

```
<s:form  action="saveXXXX"  name="myForm">
    <input type="button" onclick="myfunction(a, b);"/>
</s:form>
```

and in your function

```
function myfunction(a, b){
if ( a> b) 
      document.myForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: Doing what you suggested will do a NON-AJAX form submit.
I want to submit the FORM using AJAX <sx:submit onclick="return myfunction(a, b);" />

Comment: I want to submit the FORM CONDITIONALLY using AJAX <sx:submit onclick="return myfunction(a, b);" /> based on what the function returns.

Comment: In that case either use `$.post` or show this normal button and hide or give negative margin to '<sx:submit>' and in the function if the condition is true trigger a click on this `<sx:submit>`

Comment: I wanted to do it without tricks, it's something so basic and common.

Comment: In conclusion, the onClick event does NOT work as expected on the sj:submit. One way to deal with this is to have both buttons s:submit and the sj:submit (hidden)  then call the validation function on the s:submit, if true, trigger the onClick event of the sj:submit button. I have tried many approaches and nothing works if Someone one KNOWS a better way, let me know.

Comment: I am not sure whether trigering a click on a hidden button works. You can try giving a large negative margin to the button instead of hiding it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the ' onsubmit="return myFunction();" ' attribuite within the  tag?

> ```
> <s:form action="actionName" onsubmit="return myFunction();">
> ...
> </s:form>
> ```